# Print 2nd half of the Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list

Given a singly linked list, you have to return 2nd half elements of the linked list. If there are two middle nodes, then take second one.

I have an linked list like [1,2,3,4,5]

1->2->3->4->5

So the desired output is [3,4,5]

where I made a mistake, I made the following attempts

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def middleNode(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:

        length = 0
        while head != None:
            length += 1
            head= head.next
        cur = (length //2) +1
        leng = 0
        while head != None:
            print(cur,leng,head.val)
            if cur == leng:
                cur +=1
                return head  
            leng += 1
            head= head.next
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails because the first loop will move `head`, while the second loop expects `head` to reference the first node. Instead, when the first loop has completed, `head` is `None`, so the second loop will not iterate.

The solution is to use a different variable for the first loop, so that `head` is not moving.

There is also one mistake: `cur = (length //2) + 1` should be `cur = length //2` (because `len` starts at 0).

And the `cur +=1` just before the `return` serves no purpose -- leave it out.

So:

```
class Solution:
    def middleNode(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        node = head  # using a separate variable for the first loop
        length = 0
        while node is not None:
            length += 1
            node = node.next
        cur = length // 2
        leng = 0
        while head is not None:
            if cur == leng:
                return head  
            leng += 1
            head = head.next
```